# Output to stdout only when stdin has finished

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, stdout, stdin

What is the simplest command to wait for stdin to be finished to output something to stdout.

For example, If I write :

```
{
echo "foo"
sleep 1
echo "bar"
} | command
```

It should show

```
foo
bar
```

after 1 second (and not the first foo at the beginning).

My solution so far is to do twice `tac`, For example :

```
{
echo "foo"
sleep 1
echo "bar"
} | tac | tac
```

It has the advantage of handling all ANSI escapes/colors well.

Is they any simpler way to do what I want ?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth explaining why you want to do this - it seems strange that the command receiving the input requires it all to be streamed "at once".

Comment: But it hold in memory all the data, which might be or might not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be

```
{
 echo "foo";
 sleep 1;
 echo "bar";
} > /dev/shm/file.$$; cat /dev/shm/file.$$
```

Comment: I guess the `/dev/shm/file` has to be unique for each call, is that the case ?

Comment: And also shouldn't I be removing the /dev/shm/file afterwards ?

Comment: "Everything in tmpfs is temporary in the sense that no files will be
created on your hard drive. If you unmount a tmpfs instance,
everything stored therein is lost."

Comment: `$$` is the simplest, a cleanest method would be to use [`mktemp(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html) and `trap "rm -f $TMPFILE" EXIT` (just to say).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives using bashims:

```
cat <<EOF
$(
  echo foo
  sleep 3
  echo bar
)
EOF

# or
cat <<<"$(echo foo;sleep 3;echo bar)"
```

Internally bash will create a [safe temporary file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html), put the output of the commands into it, then pass it to `cat` stdin.
The file is destroyed as soon as the command (here `cat`) release it `stdin`.

Note usually it is better to use a stream.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the printf command :

For example

```
{
echo "foo"
sleep 1
echo "bar"
} | printf "%s\n" "$(cat)"
```

Would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Capture output, then echo/print it:

```
output=$(
    echo "foo"
    sleep 1
    echo "bar"
) 
printf "%s\n" "$output"
```

Or just:

```
printf "%s\n" "$(
    echo "foo"
    sleep 1
    echo "bar"
)"
```